# org.hibernate.envers.default_schema with MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate-envers

Is it possible to use `org.hibernate.envers.default_schema` property with MySQL database for Hiberane ORM Envers ?

I'd like to separate my original tables from Envers tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support the `org.hibernate.envers.default_schema` setting; however it does support the `org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog` option which will provide you with what you want.